# Calculating big O for a binary tree: there is a custom tag for each node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have a binary tree with `n` nodes. The tree is **not** necessarily balanced.

For each node of the tree, I count down the total number of the nodes for its left sub-tree as `nL` and then I count down the total number of the nodes for its right sub-tree as `nR`. Then I calculate `min(nL,nR)` and then assign the minimum value as a tag to the node. I repeat this process to produce appropriate tags for all the nodes of the tree.

Now I intend to calculate the big O for `sum of all the tags`. I mean, I'm curious to know if the `sum of tags` is at O(nlog(n)) or O(n) or O(n<sup>2</sup>)

---

In the most **un**balanced case, the binary tree is just a log list like figure below. In this case, I think `sum of tags` would be `0`, therefore the big O would be O(0)

[image: Like this image]

---

In the case of a perfect binary tree, the tag at the root node might be 2<sup>0</sup>(n/2<sup>0+1</sup>) and at the next level, i.e. root's left and right children, sum of tags might be 2<sup>1</sup>(n/2<sup>1+1</sup>) and for the i-th level of the perfect binary tree, the sum of tags might be 2<sup>i</sup>(n/2<sup>i+1</sup>)

At the i-th level, sum of tags might become 2<sup>i</sup>(n/2<sup>i+1</sup>)=n/2 therefore looks like that some of tags at each level might be n/2 and because a perfect binary three has a total height of log<sub>2</sub>n hence the total sum of tags might be (n/2)log<sub>2</sub>n and this implies that for a perfect binary tree, the big O for sum of tags might be O(nlog<sub>2</sub>n)

---

Now I'm not sure if my above-mentioned calculations are correct. I wonder  if anybody can help.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71727/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/42883388/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. All right, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is a custom tag for each node in a binary tree, your algorithm must visit all the nodes of the tree once in order to calculate the sum of all tags.

Therefore, the run-time is O(n).

And all of your other calculations are correct.